# What is "Program type already present"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

When i try to build my project.i got this error

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

i also to find solution in stack overflow but it didn't help.here is my build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hassan.qrscan"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

downgrade the version of dependency to

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

and also add the design dependency

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

check it once this works for me

Comment: Program type already present: **android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1**   @harsh

Answer (score 5):

The Program Type Already Present error Raised whenever your project has the repeating libraries or same library with a different version.
You can Check the Dependancies Graph by running

```
gradlew -q dependencies
```

or

```
gradle -q dependencies
```

(Required the Gradle in your class path)

Just sort out the repeating libraries, remove repeating one and error will go away.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by using same version of appcompact and design

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

but now i got this error

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1

Answer (score 1):

In place of these 2 dependencies

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
```

add these 2 lines

```
implementation('me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'){
   exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

implementation ('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'){
   exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

hopefully, this will work