# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been having an issue with duplications within my project this is the most common one it all seems to be related to the "android.support" bits

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1
```

Here is my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraryMaskLayout')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'cn.fanrunqi:waveprogress:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.15.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

Any help regarding this issue would be most appreciated.

Comment: Checkout this link it might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561384/what-is-program-type-already-present

Answer (score 19):

I included the below line, and it worked:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue as you. I searched everywhere and finally I got solution.
Simply I added one dependency of version v4. part of my manifest is as below:

```
//Change the version according to your compileSdkVersion(Mine is 28)
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did,
in your app's build.gradle file, under dependencies I excluded module 'support-v4'.

Example:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i just added

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should make the following changes in your project

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me, inside the RN project:-

```
rm -rf android

react-native eject
```

I also ran `npm i` prior to ejecting the android directory