# Android studio show this error during run. Error: Program type already present: androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, grpc-java

im tried to run my android app program through / using android studio version 3.1.4 and i have no idea what is happen while im run my program its keep showing this error

```
Error: Program type already present: androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor
```

I'd tried quick googling its answer but yet still not found answer related to my issues.

As per I'd found those issues related to class name conflict? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Below this is my build.gradle

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
            apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

            android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.ikan.elogbook"
                minSdkVersion 24
                targetSdkVersion 28
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


            }


            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }

            lintOptions {

            disable'GoogleAppIndexingWarning','HardcodedText','InvalidPackage'
                textReport true
                textOutput "stdout"
            }

            allprojects {
                repositories {
                    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

                    //this line added to resolve issue some grpc package / 
            library are not found
                    //reference bug url https://github.com/grpc/grpc- 
            java/issues/4460
                    mavenCentral()
                }
            }
}

    ext {
        supportLibraryVersion = "25.3.1"
    }


        protobuf {
            protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1' }
            plugins {
            javalite { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0" }
            grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.17.1' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
            }
        }
        generateProtoTasks {
            all().each { task ->
                task.plugins {
                    javalite {}
                    grpc { // Options added to --grpc_out
                        option 'lite' }
                }
            }
        }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.9.0'
    // You need to build grpc-java to obtain these libraries below.
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.17.1'
    // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.17.1'
    // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.17.1'
    // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1-alpha01'
}
```

Comment: please add the `build.gradle`; else this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i edited my post by putting `build.gradle`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When different types of dependency present in build.gradle file 
like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

or version conflictibility.

to avoid this you need to maintain the version of your dependency
 like this

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

you can also refer this link to know why this error occurs

[What is "Program type already present"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561384/what-is-program-type-already-present/52561600#52561600)

Comment: Its my fault not to be more details regarding what im doing. I'd edited my post by putting `build.gradle` and thanks for the above explanation.